# Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm creating vue 3 application by using Primevue theme and Vite, Typescript, Pinia.

I've just set up prpject with CMD, I see the main.ts file, it is giving an error , that

```
`import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')`
```

Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

Can you proivde the solutuion for it, how we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if there is an App.vue file in the same folder as main.ts; if not, you should correct the import path.